# Change a view visibility on all adapter items - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Well, I'm trying to hide and show a view inside all adapter items at once.

In my Room object I have a boolean property showSwitch:

```
@Entity
data class Task(
    ...
) : Serializable {
    ...
    var showSwitch: Boolean = true
    ...
    }

}
```

In my adapter I have a function to change this property to false when I want it be invisible, and call submitList() to pass again by onBindViewHolder() and recreate my View.

```
fun hideSwitchViews(){
   val newList = currentList.map { task ->
         task.showSwitch = false
         return@map task
   }
   submitList(newList)
}
```

Then in my bind function inside TaskViewHolder, I verify the property value and set a visibility that I want:

```
inner class TaskViewHolder(private val binding: ListTaskItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        ... 
       
        fun bind(task: Task) {
            ...

            if (task.showSwitch) {
                binding.timerSwitch.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                binding.timerSwitch.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            ...

        }

        ...

    }
```

My DiffCallBack

```
private class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Task>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task): Boolean {
            return oldItem.uid == newItem.uid
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }
```

In my activity I call hideSwitches() when I want to hide the view of all adapter items, but nothing happens. Some idea to this thing?? How can I do this?

//Update

Entire Adapter Code:

```
class ListTaskAdapter(
    private val selectionTaskCallback: ((Task, Boolean) -> Unit),
    private val isSelectionModeEnabledCallback: ((Task) -> Boolean),
    private val launchEditScreenCallback: ((Task) -> Unit)
) : ListAdapter<Task, ListTaskAdapter.TaskViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    fun addTask(tasks: List<Task>) {
        submitList(tasks)
    }

    fun hideSwitches() {
        val newList = currentList.map { task ->
            val newTask = task.copy()
            !newTask.showSwitch
            newTask
        }
        submitList(newList)
    }

    fun selectedTaskIds() = currentList
        .filter { it.isTaskSelected() }
        .map { it.uid }
        .toList()

    fun reset() {
        currentList.forEach {
            it.resetTaskSelection()
            it.showSwitch = true
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskViewHolder {
        return TaskViewHolder(
            ListTaskItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return currentList.size
    }

    inner class TaskViewHolder(private val binding: ListTaskItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        private val cardColorDefault =
            binding.root.context.getColorResCompat(android.R.attr.colorBackground)
        private val cardColorSelected =
            binding.root.context.getColorResCompat(android.R.attr.colorControlHighlight)

        fun bind(task: Task) {
            Log.d("task", "$task")
            addTaskItemProperties(task)

            if (!task.showSwitch) {
                binding.timerSwitch.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            if (task.isTaskSelected()) {
                checkIconAppearAnimation()
                binding.root.setCardBackgroundColor(cardColorSelected)
                selectionTaskCallback(task, true)
            }

            binding.root.setOnLongClickListener { v ->
                if (v != null) {
                    toggleSelectionMode(task)
                    selectionTaskCallback(task, task.isTaskSelected())
                }
                true
            }
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                if (isSelectionModeEnabledCallback(task)) {
                    toggleSelectionMode(task)
                    selectionTaskCallback(task,task.isTaskSelected())
                } else {
                    launchEditScreenCallback(task)
                }
            }
        }

        private fun addTaskItemProperties(task: Task) {
            binding.itemTaskName.text = task.taskName
    binding.itemTaskTime.text=task.taskMinutes.convertMinutesToHour()
            binding.timerSwitch.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.root.setCardBackgroundColor(cardColorDefault)
            configureCheckItem()
        }

        private fun configureCheckItem() {
            binding.checkItem.scaleX = 0f
            binding.checkItem.scaleY = 0f
        }

        private fun toggleSelectionMode(task: Task) {
            task.toggleTask()
            if (task.isTaskSelected()) {
                checkIconAppearAnimation()
                binding.root.setCardBackgroundColor(cardColorSelected)
            } else {
                checkIconDisappearAnimation()
                binding.root.setCardBackgroundColor(cardColorDefault)
            }
        }

        private fun checkIconAppearAnimation() {
            binding.checkItem.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).duration = 250
        }

        private fun checkIconDisappearAnimation() {
            binding.checkItem.animate().scaleX(0f).scaleY(0f).duration = 250
        }
    }

    private class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Task>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task): Boolean {
            return oldItem.uid == newItem.uid
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }
}
```

Calling the function on Activity

```
viewModel.selectionMode.observe(
            this
        ) { selectionMode ->
            changeTrashVisibilityBasedOnSelectionMode()
            if (selectionMode) {
                adapter.hideSwitches()
                Log.d("newList", "did work, submiting new list")
            } else {
                adapter.reset()
            }
        }
```

//Currently Result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0JBc.jpg

//Expected Result(Hide `switch` in all `adapterItems` when selection mode is enabled, to switch don't stay above `checkIcon`)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lkhX.jpg

Comment: Show diffcallback used by your listadapter

Comment: Are you using the normal `RecyclerView.Adapter`? If yes, are you calling `notifyDatasetChanged` inside `submitList`?

Comment: @Pawel Of course, I put on post.

Comment: @ArpitShukla I'm using DiffUtil, I forgot to put on post.

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistake here. To debug, add a log to you `bind` function and print the `Task`. Check 1) Is `bind` getting called after submitting the list or not? 2) Does it contain the right value of `showSwitch` or not?

Comment: can this be the problem `return@map task`? replace it just for `task` lambdas doesn't need explicit return statement

Comment: @ArpitShukla Ok, I did it and the `bind` isn't called after I call `hideSwitches()` on my Activity, I think that is the problem. The adapter isn't recreating the View.

Comment: @cutiko I tried it and nothing happened :/

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yeah he hasn't used === (which is good) and you said `it's comparing the same instances to themselves`. I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: @ArbitShukla `newList` contains the same instances as the original list in OP's code because the `map` lambda is returning the same item it gets. So `submitList` will be comparing two different List instances that both contain the same item instances. But even if they weren't the same instances, there would still be a problem because the items of the original list are being mutated.

Comment: @cutiko `return@map task` and `task` on the last line of the lambda have exactly the same meaning to the compiler.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I agree to your point (and your solution is definitely the better approach). It's just that even if same instance is being returned, `==` will still decide equality of two `Task` items based on the values of its member properties. So, I am not sure if your solution will solve the issue or not.

Comment: @LucasMoro Can you add you entire adapter code in the question? And if possible, also your MainActivity code from where you call `hideSwitchViews`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. In my solution the old list's items should still have `showSwitch` as false, and all of the new list's items are distinct instances that have `showSwitch` as true, so when compared in `areContentsTheSame` the result will be false.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Right, but earlier also DiffUtil would have returned false. I am not saying your code is wrong, what I said is that it won't probably solve the original problem.

Comment: In OP's code, `oldItem` and `newItem` will always be the same instance, so it would always return true. But since it didn't fix the issue for OP, yes, there probably is another problem in addition.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ah, silly me. You're right. I missed the fact the `oldItem` now has `showSwitch` set to `false`.

Comment: All right guys, I'll put all my Adapter code and post a print of the current result and the expected result

Comment: @ArpitShukla of course, updated!

Comment: `!newTask.showSwitch` won't work. Use the same function that Tenfour04 wrote in his answer. And you might also need to update you `reset` function.

Comment: It's impossible, inside a copy function I just have access of properties inside `data class` scope and not inside `Serializable` scope.

Comment: In general, this adapter is a very fragile class. You're using it like a data manager instead of its intended purpose of simply connecting data to views. To compound on this complexity, you are using a mutable data class. There are many opportunities for bugs here. The adapter should only bind views and feedback widget interactions through a listener. Outside this class, you can implement a listener that creates new immutable data classes to replace the modified ones and submits new lists back to the adapter. This should be done in ViewModel so config changes don't lose your data state.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a mutable data type. When you modify all your items to change `showSwitch`, you are changing the original items in the original list. Even though you make a copy of the list, when the DiffUtil tries to compare the two lists, it's comparing the same instances to themselves and so it cannot detect any changes.

You need to create actual new data instances so they can be compared against the old values:

```
fun hideSwitchViews(){
   val newList = currentList.map { task ->
         task.copy(showSwitch = false)
   }
   submitList(newList)
}
```

And you might as well make `showSwitch` and all other properties of your list item model class `val` to prevent this kind of problem.

Comment: Well, that's make sense, but still isn't working, Adapter isn't calling `onBindViewHolder`. And, I can't change the properties of my model class to val because the user can edit the object(task).

Comment: @LucasMoro Using `val` is actually a better approach. If user can edit the object you can use the `copy` function to create a new Task object with updated values. In general, you should try to avoid mutable properties as much as possible.

Comment: `!newTask.showSwitch` doesn't change the value of the property. It's simply an expression that does nothing. You need to use `newTask.showSwitch = false` to actually mutate it (although again I recommend an immutable class and using `copy()`). Also, you have places in `bind()` that have an if branch with no else branch. That is not going to work because ViewHolders are reused. You hide the switch if `showSwitch` is false, but you fail to show it again if `showSwitch` is true. You might be getting a recycled view holder where the switch is already hidden.

Comment: I just noticed also that `showSwitch` is not part of the data class constructor. If that is the case, you need to override `equals()` properly, or your DiffUtil cannot tell the difference between `oldItem` and `newItem`. But it would be much simpler to put all your properties in your constructor. If it doesn't make sense to persist something like `showSwitch`, you should be using a different data class for your Views than you use in Room and map between them. What are you using Serializable for? The use of the Serializable interface is highly discouraged in general.